# Java project turned into runnable jar in Eclipse --- file too big

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

I used Eclipse export -> runnable jar to turn my project into a runnable jar, however I guess I have some unused packages and the file is too big.

Is there a tool / way for me to figure out which ones are used and which ones aren't?

For Example I have the Google Web tool, but I don't think I need all of it.

I would appreciate the help!

Best,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - How to reduce the size of third-party jars to reduce the size of your application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580221/java-how-to-reduce-the-size-of-third-party-jars-to-reduce-the-size-of-your-app)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see what's inside your jar, from the command-line run:

```
jar tvf your-jar-name.jar
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to see which ones are the ones that the ones being used by the functions that are being run?

Comment: If you have maven, you can see your dependencies - i.e which jar is pulling in which other jars. Navigate to your project directory in the console, and run 'mvn dependency:tree'. This has sometimes enabled me to see where a jar I don't need is being pulled in.

Comment: If YOUR code is using GWT, then all you have to do is search for an import with the main path to their classes 'import com.google.gwt. .....'